# Tkinter and matplotlib: select coordinates with cursor

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, window, contour

For the lab where I am working, I am currently developing a software that, basically, takes a 3D matrix, where the three axis are intensity as a function of time, and perform some FT over them, obtaining a 3D matrix with intensity as a function of frequency. By slicing and plotting that 3D matrix over the Z axis, it is possible to visualize some 2D maps that contain useful information for my experiments, like this one:

[beating_map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2GHt.png)

A different source of information is obtained when summing over the X and Y axis, and plotting the results as intensity as a function of the Z axis. In our experiment, not every X and Y coordinate contains the information that we need. Therefore, making the sum over specific x-y coordinates of that 3D matrix is necessary. Example of this windows setting can be found here:

[sum_spectra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSzND.png)

Question is, is there a way that, with the cursor, tkinter can interact with matplotlib graphs and extract information about coordinates? A way in such, making some clicks, the user could select these coordinates without having to write them manually in some input box to make the sum. This is only one example of windows setting but, in fact, I have many other graphs where this interaction cursor-matplotlib-tkinter would be amazing to simplify the work.

I add the code of the map where I would like to have this interaction, just an example to work with:

```
    self.fig = Figure(figsize=(4.5, 4.5))
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)  # create axis
    self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=frame)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top")

    self.map = self.ax.contourf(x, y, intensity,
                                cmap=cmap, levels=15)  # draw board

    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, frame)
    self.toolbar.update()
    self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="bottom")
    self.canvas.draw_idle()  # update matplotlib figure
```

Simple code to include would be:

- Trigger: click on the graph
- Event: print the coordinates

With that tool is enough for me to start developing the code. If you need more of my code, please let me know. I leave one example of a MatLab software that does what I need:

[matlab_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiMgz.png)

It is possible to see that the cursor is now an arrow that, after clicking, save the x coordinates of the point where the click has been made.

Thank you very much for your time.